# Когда выполняется метод validate в custom guard?

Tags: php, laravel

Привествую. Разбираюсь с кастомной авторизацией Laravel и не могу понять для чего нужен метод validate в страже.

Есть вот такой простой страж, который авторизирует по id:

```
class CustomGuard implements Guard
{
    use GuardHelpers;
    private $request;

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function user()
    {
        if($id = $this->request->query('id')){
            return User::whereId($id)->first();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function validate(array $credentials = [])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

И собственно все работает. Да, знаю, что правильнее будет прикрутить юзерпровайдера. Но это для простоты примера и вопроса.

Как я понял, вся суть авторизации - это отдать пользователя или отдать null и всё.

Для чего нужен validate() метод и где он используется?